# Guiding a robot through a maze automatically and manually c++

Tags: c++, maze

The whole program has a function that reads in the maze that is a test file that uses
X's for walls, minus symbols for paths, a $ for end position, and + for start position,
and converts it to a better graphics maze using a draw_boxes function that draws 
in squares of different color depending on if there is a wall or a path,end position
or start position Example if it reads an X then it would put in a gray square(a wall)
a white one for - (a path),red square for $(final position) etc... .

I have the maze drawn and this function below is able to move a robot
(just a blue square) based on commands(arrow keys), but now i need to 
modify the move_robot function to be able to have the robot move to the 
on its own until it reaches the end position as well as manually 
(the user would type a command to determine whether the robot will move 
automatically or manually).

How could i do this?

```
void move_robot(int &x, int &y)
{
    while(true)
    {
        char c=wait_for_key_typed();
        int x_new=x;
        int y_new=y;
        if(c==-91)                   //ASCII for left arrow key
            x_new=x-square_side;     //(move blue robot square left 1 space)

        else if(c==-89)              //ASCII for right arrow key
            x_new=x+square_side;     //(move blue robot square right 1 space)

        else if(c==-90)              //ASCII for up arrow key
            y_new=y-square_side;     //(move blue robot square up 1 space)

        else if(c==-88)              //ASCII for down arrow key
            y_new=y+square_side;     //(move move blue robot square down 1 space)

        else if (c == 'x')           //exits the game
            hide_window();

        if(m_array[(y_new/square_side)+1][(x_new/square_side)+1]!='X')
        // if position is not a wall do the following...
        {
            draw_robot(x_new,y_new);    // calls a function that draws a blue square.
            draw_boxes(x,y,'-');    // draws white box to cover previous robot position
            x=x_new;
            y=y_new; //these update the position
        }

        if(m_array[(y_new/square_side)+1][(x_new/square_side)+1]=='$')
        // if position is the end position do the following
        {
            move_to(window_length/2,window_width/2);
            set_pen_width(2);
            set_pen_color(color::blue);
            write_string("WINNING!!!");
            char repeat=wait_for_key_typed();//to run the maze again
            if(repeat=='r')
            {   
                draw_maze();
                int x=square_side*20;
                int y=square_side*9;
                move_robot(x,y);
            }
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: next time clean up a code you paste so it's readable, please (delete unnecessary spaces and tabs)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3097556/programming-theory-solve-a-maze/3097677