# How can I make this more efficient path finding?

Tags: java

I am working on a maze solver. It runs very fast on my first 2 mazes, however, my third maze takes forever. I am supposed to be able to do it in under a minute, on reasonable hardware.

The solve method takes an immense amount of time on my high-end gaming rig.

Here is the relevant source code

```
import java.awt.Point;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;


/**
 * Created by jphamlett on 6/16/17.
 */
public class main {
    static class fileIO {

        public static String readFile(String path, Charset encoding)
                throws IOException {
            byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
            return new String(encoded, encoding);
        }
    }

    static class mazeNode {
        private Point point;
        private int dist;

        public Point getPoint() {
            return point;
        }

        public void setPoint(Point point) {
            this.point = point;
        }

        public int getDist() {
            return dist;
        }

        public void setDist(int dist) {
            this.dist = dist;
        }

        public mazeNode(Point point, int dist) {
            setPoint(point);
            setDist(dist);
        }

    }

    static class Solver {
        private String[] pathGrid;
        private int[][] gridLength;


        public void setPath(String path) {
            try {
                this.pathGrid = generatePath(fileIO.readFile(path, Charset.defaultCharset()));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public Point findA() {
            for (int row = 0; row < pathGrid.length; row++) {
                int pos = pathGrid[row].indexOf("A");
                if (pos != -1) {
                    return new Point(row, pos);
                }
            }
            return null; // Something went wrong
        }

        public Point findB() {
            for (int row = 0; row < pathGrid.length; row++) {
                int pos = pathGrid[row].indexOf("B");
                if (pos != -1) {
                    return new Point(row, pos);
                }
            }
            return null; // Something went wrong
        }

        public Boolean canMove(char symbol) {
            return symbol != '#';
        }

        public String[] generatePath(String path) {
            return path.split("\n");
        }

        public String[] getPath() {
            return this.pathGrid;
        }

        // Use BFS to solve the maze
        public int[][] solve(int[][] gridLength, Point src, Point dest) {
            if (src == null || dest == null) {
                return null;
            }
            gridLength[src.x][src.y] = 0; // Distance to self is 0
            Boolean visited[][] = new Boolean[gridLength.length][gridLength[0].length]; //Set all booleans to false
            for (Boolean[] booleans : visited) {
                Arrays.fill(booleans, Boolean.FALSE);
            }
            //System.out.println("Finished making visited array");
            visited[src.x][src.y] = Boolean.TRUE;
            Queue<mazeNode> queue = new LinkedList<>();
            mazeNode initialNode = new mazeNode(src, 0);
            queue.add(initialNode);
            while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
                mazeNode currentNode = queue.peek();
                Point currentPoint = currentNode.getPoint();
                //System.out.println("Point: " + currentPoint);
                visited[currentPoint.x][currentPoint.y] = Boolean.TRUE;
                if (currentPoint.equals(dest)) {
                    return gridLength;
                }
                queue.poll();
                // Add adjacent valid cells
                try {
                    if (canMove(pathGrid[currentPoint.x].charAt(currentPoint.y - 1)) && !visited[currentPoint.x][currentPoint.y - 1]) {
                        gridLength[currentPoint.x][currentPoint.y - 1] = currentNode.getDist() + 1;
                        queue.add(new mazeNode(new Point(currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y - 1), currentNode.getDist() + 1));
                    }
                } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {

                }

                try {
                    if (canMove(pathGrid[currentPoint.x].charAt(currentPoint.y + 1)) && !visited[currentPoint.x][currentPoint.y + 1]) {
                        gridLength[currentPoint.x][currentPoint.y + 1] = currentNode.getDist() + 1;
                        queue.add(new mazeNode(new Point(currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y + 1), currentNode.getDist() + 1));
                    }
                } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                }
                try {
                    if (canMove(pathGrid[currentPoint.x - 1].charAt(currentPoint.y)) && !visited[currentPoint.x - 1][currentPoint.y]) {
                        gridLength[currentPoint.x - 1][currentPoint.y] = currentNode.getDist() + 1;
                        queue.add(new mazeNode(new Point(currentPoint.x - 1, currentPoint.y), currentNode.getDist() + 1));
                    }
                } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                }
                try {
                    if (canMove(pathGrid[currentPoint.x + 1].charAt(currentPoint.y)) && !visited[currentPoint.x + 1][currentPoint.y]) {
                        gridLength[currentPoint.x + 1][currentPoint.y] = currentNode.getDist() + 1;
                        queue.add(new mazeNode(new Point(currentPoint.x + 1, currentPoint.y), currentNode.getDist() + 1));
                    }
                } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                }
            }
            return null; // Cannot be reached
        }

        public Solver(String path) {
            setPath(path);
        }


    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Solver solver = new Solver("mazes/maze3.txt");
        int[][] path = solver.solve(new int[solver.getPath().length][solver.getPath()[0].length()], solver.findA(), solver.findB());
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long totalTime = endTime - startTime;
        System.out.println(totalTime);
        for (int[] i : path) {
            for (int j : i) {
                System.out.print(j + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        totalTime = endTime - startTime;
        System.out.println(totalTime);

    }

}
```

Here is maze2.txt

```
###############B#############################################
##.....########.#......................................#...##
##.###.#........####################################.#.#.#.##
##.###.#.#########..........#########.......########.#.#.#.##
##.#####...........########.#.......#.#####.########.#.#.#.##
##.########################.#.#####.#.#...#.########.#.#.#.##
##............................#####.#.##.##.########.#.#.#.##
##.###.############################.#.##.##.########.#.#.#.##
##.###.##...#...#...#...#...#.......#.##.##.########.#.#.#.##
##.###....#...#...#...#...#...#######.##.##.########.#.#.#.##
##.##################################.##.##.########.#.#.#.##
##.......................................##.########.#.#.#.##
###########################################.########.#.#.#.##
###...............................#########..........#.#.#.##
########################.###########################.#.#.#.##
#........................#...........................#.#.#.##
#.######################.#############################.#.#.##
#.#..........#.........................................#.#.##
#.#.########.#.#########################################.#.##
#.#........#.#.#.........................................#.##
#.##########.#.#.#########################################.##
#............#.#.##........................................##
##############.#.#############################.#####.########
#..............................................#####........#
########################A####################################
```

I have attached maze3 because the formatting here makes it shift oddly.

https://pastebin.com/c4LhG5hT

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Maybe you should read [Programming theory: Solve a maze](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3097677/5221149). Or maybe you should debug your code, e.g. by uncommenting the print of `currentPoint`, so you can see what's going on.

Comment: You should use A* search with a manhattam distance heuristic.

Comment: Exceptions in Java should be exceptional. Don't use them for normal program flow, put in bounds checking manually. IIRC exception handling is fairly slow in Java, which might be the cause of your problems. That being said, I didn't actually look at your code in much detail - a high-level description of how it does what it does would help.

Comment: @Dukeling I tried running that code on that file, and it only catches 1 exception. On top of that, code completed in 24 milliseconds, so I guess we can all wonder what *"immense amount of time on my high-end gaming rig"* means. --- *FYI:* Reason it only generates one exception is that maze is fully enclosed in walls, so only one of the 4 possible steps from starting point `A` causes an exception.

Comment: Ahh, I was running `maze2`, not `maze3`. DOH!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the `visited` array.

First, a minor issue: The `visited` array should not be a `Boolean[][]`. Just make it a `boolean[][]`, which is automatically initialized to all `false` values, so that initialization loop can be eliminated too.

Now, the main problem is that `visited` is not marked `true` until you actually *process* that point. This means that the same point is added **many** times to the queue.

Example maze:

```
#####################
#...#...#...#...#...#
A.#1..#2..#3..#4..#5B
#...#...#...#...#...#
#####################
```

In this case, point `1` is added twice to the queue. Each point up to point `2` will also be added twice. Point `2` will be added 4 times, point `3` 8 times, point `4` 16 times, and point `5` 32 times.

As you can see, that is an exponential number of queue items for each round<sup>1</sup> to process, doubling each time multiple paths meet.

**Solution:** Rename `visited` to `queued`, and mark point `true` at the same time you add it to the queue, thus preventing the addition of the same point multiple times.

**Result:** Code completes in less then 50 milliseconds for maze 3.

<sup>1) By "round" I mean processing of all queued points that is one step further away from start (distance).</sup>